# Comparando variável char em C

Tags: c, linux, comparação

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    struct cmd1 {

        char cmd[20];

    };

    struct cmd1 cmdd;

    char cmd_ti[3] = "ti";
    char cmd_tela1[2] = "a";

    printf("\nTeste -> ");
    fgets(cmdd.cmd, 20, stdin); //O que foi digitado pelo usuario
    __fpurge(stdin);


    printf("\nDigitado pelo usuario: %s", cmdd.cmd); //teste pra ver o que ta imprimindo
    printf("\ncmd_ti:  %s", cmd_ti); //teste pra ver o que ta imprimindo
    printf("\ncmd_t1:  %s", cmd_tela1); //teste pra ver o que ta imprimindo

    if (strcmp(cmd_ti, cmdd.cmd) == 0) {

        printf("\nOK");
        printf("\n%s == %s", cmd_ti, cmdd.cmd);

    } else {

        printf("\nNOT OK");
        printf("\n%s != %s", cmd_ti, cmdd.cmd);

    }


    return(0);
}
```

Preciso que "ti" seja igual "ti" na comparação.
Já pesquisei em vários lugares e ainda não consegui entender o que está acontecendo. 
Alguém sabe me ajudar porque quando eu digito ti ele não compara com a variável que eu já deixei declarada como ti?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O valor que você está lendo de `stdin` contém o  que o usuário digitou, **inclusive o ENTER**. Se você trocar as duas linhas do `else` pelas linhas abaixo, você verá o problema:

```
    printf("\nNOT OK");
    printf("\n--%s-- != --%s--", cmd_ti, cmdd.cmd);
```

Para corrigir isso você pode remover os espaços do final de `cmdd.cmd` (se espaços são significativos então você precisa remover somente o CRLF/LF), tal como no exemplo abaixo.

```
void trimEnd(char *str) {
    char *end = str + strlen(str) - 1;
    while (end > str && isspace(*end)) end--;
    end++;
    *end = 0;
}

int main() {

    struct cmd1 {

        char cmd[20];

    };

    struct cmd1 cmdd;

    char cmd_ti[3] = "ti";
    char cmd_tela1[2] = "a";

    printf("\nTeste -> ");
    fgets(cmdd.cmd, 20, stdin); //O que foi digitado pelo usuario
    //__fpurge(stdin);


    printf("\nDigitado pelo usuario: %s", cmdd.cmd); //teste pra ver o que ta imprimindo
    printf("\ncmd_ti:  %s", cmd_ti); //teste pra ver o que ta imprimindo
    printf("\ncmd_t1:  %s", cmd_tela1); //teste pra ver o que ta imprimindo

    if (strcmp(cmd_ti, cmdd.cmd) == 0) {

        printf("\nOK");
        printf("\n%s == %s", cmd_ti, cmdd.cmd);

    } else {

        printf("\nNOT OK");
        printf("\n--%s-- != --%s--\n", cmd_ti, cmdd.cmd);

    }

    trimEnd(cmdd.cmd);
    if (strcmp(cmd_ti, cmdd.cmd) == 0) {

        printf("\nOK");
        printf("\n%s == %s", cmd_ti, cmdd.cmd);

    } else {

        printf("\nNOT OK");
        printf("\n--%s-- != --%s--\n", cmd_ti, cmdd.cmd);

    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Entendi onde está o erro agora, mas ainda não entendi o que posso fazer pra tirar o enter. Você poderia me ajudar?

Comment: O código acima remove o enter - atualize o seu browser (F5) e você verá.

Comment: Ah, entendi. Obrigada. ;)